# MySQL insert NULL value after getting value with $_REQUEST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I have input fields, but if the users leave it blank, i want to insert a null value to my database.

I request values like this:

```
$val1 = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["val"], ENT_QUOTES);
```

And then insert them to the DB:

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `val1` , `val2` , `val3`) 
VALUES ('$val1', '$val2', '$val3');
```

I have tried removing the ' around val1, val2, val3 - but then nothing gets inserted into the DB if there is no value. I have also tried something like this:

```
if (!empty($val1)) {
$val1 = "'".$val1."'";
} else {
$val1 = NULL;}
```

And then without the ' around the values - still no insert to the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first this

> INSERT INTO `table` ( `val1` , `val2` , `val3`) 
>   VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3');

will only ever insert the literal values "val1", "val2" and "val3". You aren't using any PHP variables.

Secondly, use prepared statements and parameter binding to perform your queries to protect yourself from SQL injection. For example, using PDO

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* DSN, username and password, just read the docs */);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (val1, val2, val3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$params = array(
    isset($_REQUEST['val1']) ? $_REQUEST['val1'] : null,
    isset($_REQUEST['val2']) ? $_REQUEST['val2'] : null,
    isset($_REQUEST['val3']) ? $_REQUEST['val3'] : null
);

$stmt->execute($params);
```

Also, you shouldn't HTML encode values going into a database. Perform the encoding when you display the value in an HTML document.

Comment: Plus for PDO. Definitely use a DB handler since PDO will cover a ton of things you may not want to manually write out over and over again.

Comment: Wish I could +2 for using PDO rather than the `mysql_*` functions. Too many think it's still appropriate to use those antiquated functions.

Comment: @Phil i have just tried this, and it does not insert NULL values. It inserts blank space if nothing is typed in the <input> fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you mean something like this:

```
$val1 = null;
$val2 = null;
$val3 = null;

if(isset($_REQUEST['val1']))
    $val1 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["val1"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'))."'";

if(isset($_REQUEST['val2']))
    $val2 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["val2"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'))."'";


if(isset($_REQUEST['val3']))
    $val3 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["val3"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'))."'";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` ( `val1`, `val2`, `val3`) 
VALUES ($val1, $val2, $val3)");
```

by something like this I really mean this is a simplified version of something that should be more safeguarded. You're just looking for how to pass a null value, so you cac take it from here.

Comment: You should suggest a better solution in that case

Comment: +1 for the SQL Injection aspect. Only thing I would be interested in is whether the initial `null` values need to be `$val1 = 'NULL'` so they are handled as strings (but not strings within strings) when you compile the SQL Query later. I tested it here, echoing the SQL, and they are simply handled as empty strings - not what the OP wanted.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are antiquated and should never be suggested!

Comment: @webbiedave - are you kidding? How about crawling over the whole site and docking 80% of the database related php questions then? Guy asked about null values NOT db standards. Yeah, I agree PDO is better but I don't expect someone asking a question like this to understand it at all. Now he has a PDO related answer, but if he just wants something that works and doesn't care about modernizing then mysql_query WILL STILL WORK. Might as well have told him to switch to python. Seriously, all this heat over a basic answer.

Comment: @Kai Qing: I don't see all the *heat* you're referring to (heck, I didn't even downvote it). Answers that use `mysql_*` usually do so because the questioner used them first. Even then, they'll still usually suggest switching to PDO somewhere in the answer. In this case, no DB functions were used so why suggest a frowned upon, antiquated approach? The main reason I left the comment, however, is that hopefully other readers will see it and avoid using the functions. I don't see anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Always be careful when using user-submitted values in database insertions/queries - See http://bobby-tables.com/

```
<?php

$val1 = 'NULL';
$val2 = 'NULL';
$val3 = 'NULL';

if( isset( $_REQUEST['val1'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['val1'] ) )
    $val1 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['val1'] )."'";

if( isset( $_REQUEST['val2'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['val2'] ) )
    $val1 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['val2'] )."'";

if( isset( $_REQUEST['val3'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['val3'] ) )
    $val1 = "'".mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['val3'] )."'";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` ( `val1`, `val2`, `val3`) 
VALUES ($val1, $val2, $val3)");
```

(I acknowledge the PDO argument, but, if this user, like most of the PHP community, is currently working with `mysql_*` functions, then who am I to demand they do otherwise?)

Comment: OP did not state what he's using. So why suggest an antiquated, frowned upon approach? Are you gonna suggest magic quotes next? ;)

Comment: @Lucanos Looking through the edit history, not once was any DB extension mentioned `</pedantic_rant>`

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that to insert a `null` into MySQL you have to use the SQL constant `NULL`. Quoting it will not work. This means you have to replace `'$val1'` with `NULL` in your SQL statement.

This little gotcha is something prepared statements handle for you, as will any decent ORM layer.

(You also don't usually need to HTML escape the values prior to putting into the database. But that's an unrelated problem.)